# QM eigenstate expansion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, eigenvalue, observables

Why sometime we use the integral to expand the eigenstates and sometime we use the sum to expand?  now i am read the modern quantum mechanics J.J.Sakurai text and confusing

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9551/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/359965/50583

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes eigenvalues form a discrete spectrum,such as discrete energy levels in a potential well,so we use sum.But sometimes they form a continous spectrum,such as momentum of free particle,so we use the integral.

Comment: And sometimes both (for instance, in an atom there are discrete energy levels but also a continuum of unbound states in which the electron is free)