# Are eigenfunctions always normed and orthogonal?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, conventions, normalization

I came across this simple proof:

> We show that Hermitian operators have real eigenvalues. The definition
>   of a Hermitian operator is
>
> \begin{equation} \langle \phi_i | \hat A | \phi \rangle = \langle
>  \phi_i | \hat A | \phi \rangle^* \tag{1} \end{equation}
>
> Then if $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $\hat A$, we have
>
> $$ \hat A|\psi\rangle = \lambda|\psi\rangle \tag{2}$$
>
> and therefore
>
> $$ \langle\psi|\hat A|\psi\rangle = \lambda . \tag{3}$$
>
> If $\hat A$ is hermitian, we my apply (1) so that
>
> $$\langle\psi|\hat A|\psi\rangle = \langle\psi|\hat A|\psi\rangle^*$$
>   $$\lambda = \lambda^*.$$

What I am not getting, is the step from (2) to (3). Seems to me that would be true only if $\psi$ is normed ($\langle\psi|\psi\rangle = \int \psi^*\psi \text d \tau = 1$).

Is it true in general that eigenvectors/eigenfunctions of operators are normed and orthogonal?

Comment: See also [Applications of the Spectral Theorem to Quantum Mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9551/)

Comment: @JohnRennie The duplicate question is asking about the general consequences of observables corresponding to Hermitian operators. This question seems to be asking a minor technical clarification about eigenvector normalisation.

Comment: @SeanBone Eigenvectors are defined merely as *non-zero* vectors $|\psi\rangle$ such that $A |\psi\rangle = \lambda |\psi\rangle$. There is no constraint on normalisation, and you can easily check that if $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenvector, then so is $c|\psi\rangle$ for any non-zero $c$. Hence in going from (2) to (3), there is an implicit assumption as you suspect. Commonly we take states in QM to be of unit norm, but not always.

Comment: If the wave function is not normalised  then predictions based on it will be wrong. There is no _theoretical_ basis for normalisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property of orthogonality can always be imposed, but it is not required at all in the excerpt you've cited.

The normalization of the eigenvectors can *always* be assured (independently of whether the operator is hermitian or not), by virtue of the fact that if $Av=\lambda v$, then any multiple $w=\alpha v$ of that vector will obey
$$
Aw = A\alpha v = \alpha A v = \alpha \lambda v = \lambda w.
$$
Thus, given any eigenvector of any operator, you can always assume (for free) that it's been normalized to unity.

However, this is *also* not necessary for the manipulations you've cited: if you remove that normalization, then your equation $(3)$ becomes 
$$ \langle\psi|\hat A|\psi\rangle = \lambda \langle\psi|\psi\rangle, \tag{3'}$$
in which $\lambda \langle\psi|\psi\rangle $ is (by the properties of the inner product) a real and positive number. The rest of the manipulations are unaffected: you get to
$$
\lambda \langle\psi|\psi\rangle  = \lambda^* \langle\psi|\psi\rangle
$$
and all you need to do is divide by $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle $.

Answer (score 0):

One can always work in an orthonormal basis. By default, we do this when working with quantum mechanics for convenience.

Note that if $\hat{A}|\psi\rangle=\lambda|\psi\rangle,\,\hat{A}^\dagger|\phi\rangle=\mu|\phi\rangle$ then $\langle \phi|\hat{A}|\psi\rangle$ is equal to both $\lambda\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$ and $\mu^\ast\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$, so either the vectors are orthogonal or $\lambda=\mu^\ast$. We can even ensure orthogonality in this special case with a basis change called the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). Finally, we can rescale eigenvectors to have unit norm. This allows such convenient results as $\operatorname{id}=\sum_i |i\rangle\langle i|$ so that $|\Psi\rangle=\sum_i \langle i|\Psi\rangle|i\rangle$.